# Make mistaking a path, failing with "No rule to make target"

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm trying to build [trace-cmd.git](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/rostedt/trace-cmd.git) from source; the worst is, *I had already built this once on this same machine, succesfully*; however didn't keep any notes, and cannot tell what could have happened in the meantime.

So now I'm trying to rebuild, and I get the dreaded:

```
trace-cmd$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `/media/disk/trace-cmd/event-parse.c', needed by `event-parse.o'.  Stop.
```

Ok, let's see what the debug says:

```
trace-cmd$ make -d
...
    Successfully remade target file `trace_python_dir'.
    Pruning file `tc_version.h'.
    Considering target file `libparsevent.a'.
      Considering target file `event-parse.o'.
        Pruning file `/media/disk/src/trace-cmd/event-parse.c'.        ## THIS EXISTS!
        Pruning file `.event-parse.d'.
        Considering target file `/media/disk/trace-cmd/event-parse.c'. ## THIS DOESN'T???
         File `/media/disk/trace-cmd/event-parse.c' does not exist.
        ...
          Trying pattern rule with stem `event-parse.w'.
          Trying implicit prerequisite `/media/disk/trace-cmd/SCCS/s.event-parse.w'.
         Trying pattern rule with stem `event-parse'.
         Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `/media/disk/trace-cmd/event-parse.w'.
         No implicit rule found for `/media/disk/trace-cmd/event-parse.c'.
         Finished prerequisites of target file `/media/disk/trace-cmd/event-parse.c'.
        Must remake target `/media/disk/trace-cmd/event-parse.c'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/media/disk/trace-cmd/event-parse.c', needed by `event-parse.o'.  Stop.
```

OK, what is going on? Of course the actual file exists:

```
trace-cmd$ ls -la /media/disk/src/trace-cmd/event-parse.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 121563 2013-03-20 19:03 /media/disk/src/trace-cmd/event-parse.c
```

... but this is `/media/disk/src/trace-cmd/event-parse.c`!! And:

- `make` already found it once;
- yet `make` decided to, for some reason, drop the `/src/` from the path,

... and that file obviously doesn't exist:

```
trace-cmd$ ls /media/disk/trace-cmd/event-parse.c
ls: cannot access /media/disk/trace-cmd/event-parse.c: No such file or directory
```

Can someone explain me, for what possible reason could `make` decide to drop a part of the path, such that it cannot find a file, that it originally had a correct reference to?

Answer (score 1):

Got it - thought I'd focus on that `.event-parse.d` file:

```
trace-cmd$ head -n 4 .event-parse.d 
event-parse.o: /media/disk/trace-cmd/event-parse.c \
 /usr/include/stdio.h /usr/include/features.h /usr/include/bits/predefs.h \
 /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h \
 /usr/include/gnu/stubs.h /usr/include/gnu/stubs-32.h \
```

... and indeed, that is the wrong path there... What happens if I delete this `.d` file?

```
trace-cmd$ rm .event-parse.d 
trace-cmd$ make
  COMPILE FPIC           event-parse.o
make: *** No rule to make target `/media/disk/trace-cmd/trace-seq.c', needed by `trace-seq.o'.  Stop.
```

Oh, my. There must be more of them:

```
trace-cmd$ ls .*.d
.event-parse.d      .plugin_kmem.d          .trace-filter.d      .trace-options.d    .trace-seq.d
.kbuffer-parse.d    .plugin_kvm.d           .trace-ftrace.d      .trace-output.d     .trace-split.d
.kernel-shark.d     .plugin_mac80211.d      .trace-graph.d       .trace-plot-cpu.d   .trace-stack.d
...
```

... and indeed, there are; apparently cached files from previous compilation, where indeed I compiled in another directory. And if I delete them all:

```
trace-cmd$ rm .*.d
trace-cmd$ make
...
gcc --shared event-parse.o trace-seq.o parse-filter.o parse-utils.o trace-util.o trace-input.o trace-ftrace.o trace-output.o trace-recorder.o trace-restore.o trace-usage.o trace-blk-hack.o kbuffer-parse.o ctracecmd_wrap.o -o ctracecmd.so
Note: to build the gui, type "make gui"
      to build man pages, type "make doc"
```

Well, that seemingly worked; I'm back to being happy again `:)`
Cheers!

Comment: Next time, consider using `remake` to debug such issues.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment, @BasileStarynkevitch - had heard about `remake` before, but didn't occur to me that it applied to this situation. Cheers!